# Highlight All Mondays in Orange Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to use conditional formatting to highlight all Mondays in a row in orange.

This is what I have found and attempted so far;

```
=WEEKDAY($B$1:$AF$1)=0
```

But none of the Mondays are highlighted (there are definitely some present in the row). How can I use conditional formatting to highlight the Mondays?

Comment: Are any other cell highleghter. (Not at a PC with ms office atm, but I know the first day of the week can be either Sunday **or** Monday.  Not sure if those regional settings apply here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've two issues in your formula:

- your formula should refer only to one cell (the one which is active when you write your formatting)
- default day numbering of [`WEEKDAY` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is 1 to 7, it'll never be 0 (in default format Monday is 2)

[image]

Comment: `WEEKDAY` is 1 to 6? What happens to the 7th day in the week?

Answer (score 5):

Your formula might have worked when *all* those days are Mondays.

In the *Conditional Formatting*, you need to enter the formula for *one cell*. It will be automatically applied to all others, relative or absolute, as requested.

So select all the cells you want it applied to, and in the decision formula, write `=WEEKDAY(B1)=0` (or `=WEEKDAY(B$1)=0`).

To verify what I claim, you can click on for example E1, and look up the formula in the conditional formatting, and it will show `=WEEKDAY(E1)=0` - as it should.

Comment: How do you know what cell is being considered as the basis when using A1 formatting? (This is why I prefer R1C1 formatting)

Comment: Always the first of the cells you select.(hey I didn't code it... )